Allen charge -- why in state court and how often does it produce a verdict
Watching the Daniel Penny case in New York it seems the jury came back with a note saying they are deadlocked. Consequently the judge has issued an Allen charge to try to get a verdict.
A couple of questions:

The Allen charge arose from a USSC decision about a federal case. So why does it apply in the completely different jurisdiction of New York's State criminal court? It doesn't seem to be a civil rights issue that would be incorporated to the states, more a matter of procedure.

How often does an Allen charge actually get a verdict from the jury? I'm pretty sure were I on a jury and received such a charge I'd be unlikely to change my mind, since, by that time, I would have already taken my responsibility very seriously. Especially so were I a jury member on a homicide trial.



The US has no good statistics on charges brought and there is no database of all cases

Do you have a reference you can cite for the actual wording of the charge that was issued?  Because the example in your link isn't a "charge" by any definition.  It's really a request, encouragement, nothing more than standard jury instructions really.  (By any reasonable interpretation...)

Why state court?
It doesn’t apply to the states.
Or rather, Allen v. United States (1896) is binding precedent only in Federal courts and each state can allow or disallow similar instructions by their own statute or case law. Some states allow them, some don’t. Either way, each state will have its own precedential case that establishes that; that case will almost certainly cite Allen as persuasive precedent.
They’re just colloquially called “Allen charges” as a convenient label.
How often are the used and how often do they work?
No idea.
I’ve looked - which is to say I’ve Googled and checked Google scholar - and I can’t find any statistics. It could be a good thesis topic if you want to pursue a higher law degree.

Again, very wrong. Allen is binding in all state and federal courts in the United States. I don't know how one could look at the law and conclude otherwise.

@bdb484 because, unlike some people, I understand how the law works

@bdb484, "Binding"?  What, specifically, is binding?  FWIW, All I know about an Allen charge is what is in the link in the question, but I don't know how anyone could look at that link and conclude that "urging" a jury is at all binding.  Especially when you include all the disclaimers and caveats in the example.  But if you have a good answer to the question then please provide it!

@DaleM Maybe in Australia? But in the United States, SCOTUS decisions are binding on all lower courts. This is about as basic a legal principle as you can get.

@bdb484, so are you saying that juries are required to come to a unanimous decision once they have been given an Allen "urging"?  And considering the example in the link, how would the judge distinguish between Allen urging and (regular) urging?  The "model" example given is pretty milquetoast to be considered a "charge"...

I look forward to a proper answer from a legal professional that clears this up then...

SCOTUS decisions are absolutely not binding on all states. They are binding on federal courts and sometimes binding on the states insofar as they have been incorporated based on the 14th amendment's due process clause. https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/incorporation_doctrine In the case of something like Roe it was only binding on the states because of this incorporation: it was a matter of civil rights. And criminal procedure is certainly not that. DaleM's answer is excellent your comments are simply wrong. I looked more -- some states allow "Allen" charges, some explicitly forbid them.

@FraserOrr You're certainly free to believe that, but I'd say you're misunderstanding the decision reached in Allen. SCOTUS wasn't saying that courts must issue an Allen charge, only that the Allen charge did not violate the defendant's federal right to a fair trial. In that sense, the rule is binding on all courts. At the same time, individual states may provide greater rights to a defendant and therefore prohibit Allen charges in their own courts.

So if a state court were considering whether an Allen charge was impermissible based on federal law, it would be bound by the SCOTUS decision. If it were considering whether an Allen charge were impermissible under state law, the SCOTUS decision wouldn't really be on point to begin with.
